# Excel to XML: Round decimals to the nearest hundredth and keep hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, excel

I followed [this guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-an-xml-data-file-and-xml-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-HA010342365.aspx) to export an Excel Spreadsheet as an XML data file and then [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp) to display the XML sheet as an HTML table on my website. It worked great. Now I "only" have to small issues remaining that I couldn't get solved.

(1) The output table contains numbers  like 1.325667 but also lots of 0s. I would like the zeroes to be displayed as 0.00 and the numbers with many decimals to be displayed as 1.33. Basically, each number should be displayed with two decimals.

(2) The excel sheet contains hyperlinks to other pages on my website that I would like to keep when rendering the XML data file and then the HTML table. So far, that didn't work. Is this possible?

**UPDATE** I figured this part out. By breaking up the hyperlinks in just their character-strings, then adding new columns for these character strings, and then tweaking the source code to including

```
document.write("<tr><td><a href='");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("character-string")0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write(".php'>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</a></td>");
```

I was able to include hyperlinks.

The Excel-Sheet is formatted with these two aspects already integrated, but the conversion to an XML file seems to be the problem.

Thank you so much for your help (again and again :-))

**UPDATE** I now also found a way to do the rounding in Excel, but I'm still stuck with integers and numbers with only one decimal. Basically, I now "only" need a way to show every number with two decimal points, applying to integers (e.g. 0 should 0.00) and numbers with one decimal (e.g. 1.5 should be 1.50). JohnnyReeves' answer seems to be on the right track but I couldn't get it to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Number Object has the method **toFixed()**:

   1.325667.toFixed(2) = 1.33.
2. Running inside the loop of the XML, select the URL and add it to the link:

   document.write("< a href=" + x[i].getElementsByTagName(< your URL link>) + ">);

   document.write("some text");

   document.write("< /a>");

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I may need a bit more guidance :-)

Where in this code string `document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);` would I add `toFixed(2)` so that it automatically rounds each number to the second decimal. 

I believe that your solution for the hyperlink problem would also require me to insert the link for each individual row, right?

Answer (score 0):

The Number.toFixed method will only work on floating point values (eg: 2.1), but not on integers (eg: 2, or 0).  You will need to convert your number type to a string type so you can format it for display and get consistent results regardless of the input.  A function like this should do the trick:

```
function formatNumber(value) {
    var parts,
        trailingDigits,
        formattedRemainder;

    // Coerce the supplied value to a String type.
    value = String(value);

    // Break the supplied number into two parts, before and after the dot
    parts = value.split(".");

    // If there was no dot, there will only be one "part" and we can just
    // add the trailing zeros.
    if (parts.length === 1) {
        formattedRemainder = "00";
    }
    else {
        trailingDigits = parts[1];

        if (trailingDigits.length === 0) {
            // A dot, but no digits. (eg: 2. -> 2.00)
            formattedRemainder = "00";
        }
        else if (trailingDigits.length === 1) {
            // Add an extra trailing zero (eg: 2.1 -> 2.10)
            formattedRemainder = trailingDigits + "0";
        }
        else {
            // Just take the last two trailing digits.
            formattedRemainder = trailingDigits.substring(0, 2);
        }
    }

    // Build the final formatted string for display.
    return parts[0] + "." + formattedRemainder;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work, but maybe that's because of my lack of experience with webdesign and XML. I put your code in the head of my page but it doesn't change the numbers in the table. Do I have to change anything with the other code?

Comment: You need to invoke it, eg: `document.write(formatNumber(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));`

Comment: I also tried that, but with no luck, it just prevents the table from populating with the data from the XML file.